# PDF annotation tools for the iPad

Tags: ipad, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPad PDF Reader with annotation support?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16863/ipad-pdf-reader-with-annotation-support)

I'm considering purchasing a PDF annotation app for the iPad; mostly something that allows me to highlight, add handwritten and typed notes, comments, etc.

I have three closely-related questions:

1. Does anybody know of a **recent review** of PDF annotation tools for the iPad / iPad 2?
2. Alternatively, does anybody have/know of a list of **pros-and-cons** of the different PDF annotation tools for the iPad?
3. Does **Adobe** have any official application for the iPad? If not, is there are a reason why they don't?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A recent review written on March 15th, 2011 placed the top 3 PDF annotation apps.

> http://www.brandsonly.nl/ipad/2011/03/15/the-3-best-ipad-pdf-markup-apps/

1. The pros and cons of the apps are included in the response to 1.
2. Adobe has a few official applications for the iPad including one that I use very often which is Adobe Ideas.

IMO, I bought the iPad app, UPAD. It serves various purposes as a notebook but also includes the functionality of doing what you would like to do with PDF's. A very functional app indeed, but if what you search for is pure PDF annotating, then the provided link with the top PDF annotating apps is your best choice.

Comment: the link is dead!

Answer (score 1):

I have just been using [iAnnotate PDF](http://www.ajidev.com/iannotate/) it's very good for marking PDF's on the go. It's £6.99 in the UK app store. Not sure about the USA price.